# Can't set outlets when I push a UIViewController without animating

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationController with which I push UIViewControllers onto using `pushViewController:animated:`. After this, I call a method on that incoming view to set some of its IB outlets. Unfortunately, these only get set when I animate the view.

So this will work:

```
MyViewController *newView = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
[newView updateOutletsForObject:myObject];
```

But this won't:

```
MyViewController *newView = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:NO];
[newView updateOutletsForObject:myObject];
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the parent view controller shouldn't be setting up the child's outlets. You should be handling IBOutlet connections in `-viewDidLoad` of the child view controller.

Comment: Hi Mark. Updating the outlets in `-viewDidLoad` does work, but wouldn't `-viewDidLoad` have been called before I tried to run my `-updateOutletsForObject:` method?

Comment: Yes but that's not the point. Encapsulation is key here. Doing it this way leaves each controller only responsible for the view it is actually controlling. Moving this work off to `-viewDidLoad` reduces coupling between the two controllers.